# postgresql: aggregate data in a set of date ranges

Tags: postgresql, range, aggregate-functions

I have the table

```sql
CREATE TABLE t1
(
  id           serial           NOT NULL,
  in_quantity  bigint           NULL,
  price        money            NOT NULL,
  out_quantity bigint           NULL,
  stamp        timestamp        NOT NULL
);
```

with such data, for example (date is the same, but not the time)

```sql
INSERT INTO t1 (in_quantity, price, out_quantity, stamp)
VALUES
( 100, 10.00, NULL, '2014-10-20 00:00:00'), -- id =  1
( 200, 11.00, NULL, '2014-10-20 00:01:00'), -- id =  2
( 300, 12.00, NULL, '2014-10-20 00:02:00'), -- id =  3
(NULL, 13.00,  400, '2014-10-20 00:03:00'), -- id =  4
(NULL, 14.00,  500, '2014-10-20 00:04:00'), -- id =  5

( 600, 15.00, NULL, '2014-10-20 00:15:00'), -- id =  6
( 700, 16.00, NULL, '2014-10-20 00:16:00'), -- id =  7
( 800, 17.00, NULL, '2014-10-20 00:17:00'), -- id =  8
(NULL, 18.00,  900, '2014-10-20 00:18:00'), -- id =  9
(NULL, 19.00, 1000, '2014-10-20 00:19:00'), -- id = 10

(2300, 23.00, NULL, '2014-10-20 00:23:00'), -- id = 11
(2400, 24.00, NULL, '2014-10-20 00:24:00'); -- id = 12
```

I need to fetch lines  from this table with maximum in and out quantities for each date range in a particular set.
Set for example:

```sql
( "2014-10-20 00:00:00" : "2014-10-20 00:05:00" ]
( "2014-10-20 00:05:00" : "2014-10-20 00:10:00" ]
( "2014-10-20 00:10:00" : "2014-10-20 00:15:00" ]
( "2014-10-20 00:15:00" : "2014-10-20 00:20:00" ]
( "2014-10-20 00:20:00" : "2014-10-20 00:25:00" ]
```

and my desired result with this example would be

```sql
interval begin        | interval end          | max_in_q | max_in_q_id | max_out_q | max_out_q_id 
======================+=======================+==========+=============+===========+=============
"2014-10-20 00:00:00" | "2014-10-20 00:05:00" | 300      | 3           | 400       | 4
"2014-10-20 00:05:00" | "2014-10-20 00:10:00" | NULL     | NULL        | NULL      | NULL        
"2014-10-20 00:10:00" | "2014-10-20 00:15:00" | NULL     | NULL        | NULL      | NULL        
"2014-10-20 00:15:00" | "2014-10-20 00:20:00" | 800      | 8           | 1000      | 10
"2014-10-20 00:20:00" | "2014-10-20 00:25:00" | 2400     | 12          | NULL      | NULL
```

So. I can generate set like that with a query like this

```sql
SELECT
   i::timestamp AS dleft,
   i::timestamp + '1 hour' AS dright 
FROM
   generate_series('2014-10-20 00:00:00'::timestamp, '2014-10-20 23:00:00'::timestamp, '1 hour') AS i
```

But I cant figure how can I make aggregate function run for every one of this little ranges and how can I join results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to realize, you need your `id`s too for each aggregated value, which isn't an easy query, in any RDBMS.

This problem mainly solved with [`DISTINCT ON`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT) in PostgreSQL:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (s)
  s ts_start, s + '5 minutes' ts_end, in_quantity max_in_q, id max_in_id
FROM
  generate_series('2014-10-20 00:00:00'::timestamp, '2014-10-20 00:20:00'::timestamp, '5 minutes') s
LEFT JOIN
  t1 ON stamp <@ tsrange(s, s + '5 minutes', '(]')
ORDER BY
  s, in_quantity DESC NULLS LAST;
```

But this only allows you, to select one max/min value, and the whole row, which they belongs to.

If you really need both max column, you need to write self-joins and sub-queries, which won't be so fast:

```
SELECT
  lower(r) ts_start, upper(r) ts_end, max_in_q, max_in.id max_in_id, max_out_q, max_out.id max_out_id
FROM (
  SELECT
    r, max(in_quantity) max_in_q, max(out_quantity) max_out_q
  FROM
    generate_series('2014-10-20 00:00:00'::timestamp, '2014-10-20 00:20:00'::timestamp, '5 minutes') s,
    tsrange(s, s + '5 minutes', '(]') r
  LEFT JOIN
    t1 ON stamp <@ r
  GROUP BY
    r
  ORDER BY
    r
) m
LEFT JOIN
  t1 max_in ON max_in.in_quantity = max_in_q
LEFT JOIN
  t1 max_out ON max_out.out_quantity = max_out_q;
```

**Note**: with this second version, you need to deal with duplicates yourself, because `in_quantity` and `out_quantity` isn't unique.

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/4d336/18)

Answer (score 1):

I think this could be quite straightforward with the help of [range type](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/rangetypes.html):

```
WITH data(in_quantity,price,out_quantity,stamp) AS (VALUES
( 100::int8, 10.00, NULL::int8, '2014-10-20 00:00:00'::timestamp), -- id =  1
( 200, 11.00, NULL, '2014-10-20 00:01:00'), -- id =  2
( 300, 12.00, NULL, '2014-10-20 00:02:00'), -- id =  3
(NULL, 13.00,  400, '2014-10-20 00:03:00'), -- id =  4
(NULL, 14.00,  500, '2014-10-20 00:04:00'), -- id =  5

( 600, 15.00, NULL, '2014-10-20 00:15:00'), -- id =  6
( 700, 16.00, NULL, '2014-10-20 00:16:00'), -- id =  7
( 800, 17.00, NULL, '2014-10-20 00:17:00'), -- id =  8
(NULL, 18.00,  900, '2014-10-20 00:18:00'), -- id =  9
(NULL, 19.00, 1000, '2014-10-20 00:19:00'), -- id = 10

(2300, 23.00, NULL, '2014-10-20 00:23:00'), -- id = 11
(2400, 24.00, NULL, '2014-10-20 00:24:00')
)
SELECT
   tsrange(i,i+INTERVAL '1h','[)') r,
   max(in_quantity)                max_in_q,
   max(out_quantity)               max_out_q
  FROM generate_series('2014-10-20 00:00:00'::timestamp,
                       '2014-10-20 23:00:00'::timestamp, '1 hour') AS i
  LEFT JOIN data d ON tsrange(i,i+INTERVAL '1h','[)') @> d.stamp
 GROUP BY r
 ORDER BY r;
```

<kbd>Check on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/f6b64/1)</kbd>

I used `LEFT JOIN` here as I thought you would like to see all ranges, adopt to your needs.